# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute *** in Python with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, element, web-component, attributeerror

I am trying to get one information which is a text (or you can say it string).
The link is here http://www.mackolik.com/Mac/2843687/Besiktas-Atiker-Konyaspor

I wanna get ***"66.000.000"*** value from below elements.

```html
<tr class="team-value">
    <td colspan="10" align="center" style="color:green;">İlk 11 Değeri : 66.000.000 EUR</td>
</tr>
```

I used many types of codes. But I belive the value is coming from another databes or working with another scripts. When I try to find from sting it gives empty value. So when I try to print with the following code, I get following errors.

```
temp = soup.find("tr", {"class': 'team-value"}).string

print(temp)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "element.py", line 23, in
>   
>       temp = soup.find("tr", {"class': 'team-value"}).string AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'

If someone can get me the all value ***"İlk 11 Değeri : 66.000.000 EUR"***, I can separet the integer value.

Thanks.

Comment: You should have a dict (you have a set) in the second argument. I'm voting to close this as a typo.

Comment: @t.m.adam: I think this approach is doomed even with that correction. I'm about to answer.

Comment: @BillBell you mean `.string` yes?  Sure, go ahead.

Answer (score 2):

Mahir, when you use requests to obtain a copy of the page it doesn't contain that number initially, as shown by this code. I expect that javascript is downloaded that gets that number afterwards.

```
>>> url = 'http://www.mackolik.com/Mac/2843687/Besiktas-Atiker-Konyaspor'
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get(url).content
>>> page.find(b'66.000.000')
-1
```

You can, however, use selenium to load the page into the Chrome browser, like this.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> driver.get(url)
```

Then you can identify the item you want using an xpath expression.

```
>>> td = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@id="dvHomeSquad"]//td[@colspan="10"]')
>>> td.text
'İlk 11 Değeri : 66.000.000 EUR'
```

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for suggesting selenium. I haven't try it before. But when I try your code it gives a different errors about drivers. But I am using the latest version of Chrome. Do you have an idea what wrong?
'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", lin
e 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)'

Comment: File "C:\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 992, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "element.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", l
ine 62, in __init__

Comment: It appears to me that you might need the file chromedriver.exe. If you're on Windows then it works if you put it in the c:\Python3x folder.

Comment: I download it to python folder. But this time chrome trying to open a page and gives error.  `chromedriver.exe stopped working. debug or close the program.`

When I close the program python gives same error. I really dont get it :S

Comment: Have you tried running the script I put in my answer **exactly** as it appeared? If so then I would suggest that you put another question on SO where you provide as much detail as possible: Windows and Chrome versions, etc.

Comment: If you add a comment here when you add your question I'll try to answer but I'm not an expert about configuring selenium

Comment: Thanks for help i will read datasheets of selenium. At least you give me an other option. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = soup.find('tr', {'class':'team-value'}).find('td').string
```

This is using beautifulsoup4.

Comment: I tried this one, I got following error again.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "element.py", line 23, in <module>
    temp = soup.find('tr', {'class':'team-value'}).find('td').string
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'`

Comment: Is that using the snippet you gave as the soup?

Comment: I am using parser for it, 
`url='http://www.mackolik.com/Mac/2843687/Besiktas-Atiker-Konyaspor'

url_oku = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(url_oku, 'html.parser')`